# Javascript: how to find the content of h3 header with id "map"?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-maps

I have a web page with a Google Map which works well. Instead of having the city name hardcoded to "Bochum" there, I'd like to find the header

```
<h3 id="city"><i>Bochum</i></h3>
```

and use that value in my init() function.

I'm probably missing something minor in the code below. Please help me and please refer me to the API reference for such a "child", my Javascript skills are very rusty.

Also I wonder, how could I pass one more value through my h3 header, like the color for my marker?

Thank you!
Alex

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
        h1,h2,h3,p { text-align: center; }
    #map { width: 400; height: 200; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init() {
        for (var child in document.body.childNodes) {
                child = document.body.childNodes[child];
                if (child.nodeName == "H3")
                        alert(child);
        }

    // use the #city value here instead
    city = 'Bochum';

    if (city.length > 1)
        findCity(city);
}

function createMap(center) {
    var opts = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };
    return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), opts);
}

function findCity(city) {
    var gc = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    gc.geocode( { "address": city}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var pos = results[0].geometry.location;
            var map = createMap(pos);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                title: city,
                position: pos,
            });
        }
    });
}
</script>
<head>
<body onload="init();">
<h3 id="city"><i>Bochum</i></h3>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For a start, you should really be using jQuery: http://jquery.com/

Comment: Why loading a 80kb-library for doing a thing can be done with one line?

Comment: @Dr.Molle: it is only 26kb once compressed. It is a trade off between making the application code simpler and more reliable vs making the total page size smaller. For example, if we use $('#city').text(), then it is shorter and won't break if the <i> tag gets removed.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't to learn jQuery yet...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To include more data, you could use attributes:

```
<h3 id="city" data-citycolor="red"><i>Bochum</i></h3>
```

And get them out like this:

```
var city = document.getElementById("city");
var name = city.textContent || city.innerText;
var color = city.getAttribute("data-citycolor");
```

I think that you would be better off using jQuery, even if it is a 26kb library file, since then you can simplify it to this:

```
var city = $("#city");
var name = city.text();
var color = city.data("citycolor");
```

Note that you used "#city" in you comment, and with jQuery, you can use that exact string in your code. That's a good win. It also makes it trivial to use $(".city") in the future, if you want to have more of these on one page.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm confused: should I use node.innerHTML, node.innerText or node.textContent and why?

Comment: innerHTML will include the <i> tags, which you don't want. innerText and textContent will both get just the text (no html tags), however not all browsers support innerText, so I've included textContent as an alternative way to get at the data. If you use the jQuery solution, you can largely ignore cross-browser issues like this, since it has the same (simple) api in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the h3 has an ID, no?

```
var city = document.getElementById('city').innerText;
```

Or, using jQuery:

```
var city = $('#city').text();
```

Comment: I would have voted this up if you hadn't used a regex on html. Use innerText/textContent instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the ID 'city' is unique(what an ID has to be):

```
document.getElementById('city').getElementsByTagName('i')[0].firstChild.data
```

Answer (score 1):

The id attribute should be unique for the page - in other words you shouldn't have any other elements with id="city".  Assuming that's the case, here's an example of what you could do:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init()
    {
        var node = document.getElementById("city");
        var cityName = node.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
        alert("Found city name: " + cityName);
    }
</script>

<body onload="init();">
    <h3 id="city"><i>Bochum</i></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

As a suggestion, I would lose the <i> and </i> tags, and instead add a style rule for your h3 node.  In that case, the cityName would be just node.innerHTML.